# What makes smartpointers better than normal pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers

What makes smartpointers better than normal pointers?

Comment: they're smarter :)

Comment: They manage the lifetime of the pointed-to object by some way or another.

Comment: @jalf: +1 hurray for stating the obvious :)

Comment: -1 This is a typical I-want-rep-question. Why don't you ask what smart pointers are in the first place? Or what a specific aspect of them is good for, then you'd know why they are 'superior' (what *is* superior anyway?)

Comment: Nothing. They serve different purposes. Try to use a search enginge next time.

Comment: why would he use a search engine? The reason for SO has always been to replace random Google results. Comments telling people to Google are not helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They simplify the problem of resource management. Once you hold your resources within smart pointers they will release memory for you when they go out of scope applying [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) techniques.

This has two main advantages: code is safer (less prone to resource leaks) and programming is easier as you do not need to remember in each part of your code whether the resource you are holding must be manually released.

Comment: "they will release memory for you when they go out of scope" ... true for i.e. std::auto_ptr, but not for smart pointers based on other policies like ref-counting.

Answer (score 7):

The principal advantage is that the memory pointed to by the smart pointer will be automatically deallocated when the pointer does out of scope. With regular pointers, you have to manage the memory yourself.

Answer (score 7):

A raw pointer doesn't take ownership of the resource it points to. When the pointer goes out of scope, the object it pointed to is unaffected. Often, you want some kind of ownership semantics where, when the pointer goes out of scope, the object it points to should either be deleted, or at least be notified that there's one less pointer pointing to it.

That is what smart pointers do.

A `shared_ptr` implements reference-counting, so that when all pointers to an object are destroyed, the object gets deleted.

Others, like `scoped_ptr` or `unique_ptr` or `auto_ptr` implement various forms of exclusive ownership. When a `scoped_ptr` is destroyed, it deletes the object it points to.

Comment: +1 for the one answer that explains and also does reduce smart pointer to 1 or 2 smart pointer policies.

Answer (score 5):

Fewer memory leaks.   Maybe Scott Meyers can make it clearer for you:

1. [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876)
2. [More Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163371X)

Answer (score 3):

Automatic reference counting and deallocation.

Comment: Especially in the face of exceptions!

Answer (score 2):

While agreeing with the other answers in practice, I'd just like to say that nothing makes smart pointers better in principle, unless they happen to be what works for your application. That is, if a smart pointer isn't needed, it isn't better.

If the smart pointer you're talking about is std::auto_ptr, it could well be substantially worse than a simple pointer. But that's not so much a smart pointers issue as a semantics of assignment issue.

That said, smart pointers very often are useful - even the dreaded auto_ptr - especially (as mentioned above) WRT exception safety.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:

[Smart Pointers](http://ootips.org/yonat/4dev/smart-pointers.html)